# padding on Bootstrap components

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

Im working on bootstrap but unsure if im using the columns correctly

I cant seem to get the margin and padding correct.

Please see image below and [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28XuT/)

[image]

```
  <div class="row">
                <!-- MAIN LEFT CONTENT! -->
                <div class="col-lg-9">

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                         <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                               <p><span>Pending approval</span>.Your profile is bring approved. This means others can't search for you just yet.</p>
                            </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 hot-not">
                               <div class="row">
                                  <div class="thumbnail">
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule `.col-xs-5` (line 793) is fixing the width:

```
.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666666666667%;
}
```

Set it to 50%:

```
.col-xs-5 {
  width: 50%;
}
```